# Could not load file or assembly 'Excel, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93517dbe6a4012fa' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I have an MVC application that has been running in debug mode with no problems. Suddenly today I get an error when loading the browser screen (it compiles OK) that cannot find assembly "Excel" which I don't use in the application and have never previously referenced it. Not even sure what assembly it should be.
ANy help?
Thanks
Martin

Comment: What does the stack trace tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got a suggestion in your Yellow Screen of Death to turn on the assembly binding logging, like so:

*To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.*

Se also [how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net).

If you do this, you will get a lot more detailed information on what whent wrong and why. If that does not in itself give you enough to solve the issure, perhaps share the detailed log here. When you're done, remember to remove the registry value again, lest performance will suffer.